# Is autosys a freeware tool for job scheduling? How to configure Autosys for scheduling a batch process in windows?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autosys

Is autosys a freeware tool for job scheduling? How to configure Autosys for scheduling a batch process in windows?How to implement scheduling process using Autosys and JIL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, autosys is not free. It's a commercial product from CA. Moreover, it needs a dedicated infrastructure. User manual has more details about `Job Interface Language` used to schedule jobs on autosys

Comment: Can anyone please help me getting a sample implementation of Autosys in windows platform..

Comment: Or to get the Autosys Java API